# Chrome not found inside docker container

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run Selenium test inside docker container but getting

> Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  webtest:
    build: .
```

**testfile.js**

```
var sw = require('selenium-webdriver');
let driver = new sw.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
    .build();
driver.get('https://www.google.com/');
```

When I am running testfile.js outside of the container it's working. facing problem to run inside the container only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub" by "http://chrome:4444/wd/hub", and configure docker networking. Inside the container "localhost" is not your host machine, therefore the port is not reachable and refusing the connection. The port mapping applies only between the container and the host machine.

At least create a link between the containers (see below), better directly configure the networks
(https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  webtest:
    build: .
    links:
     - chrome
```